# Evitar mostrar la ruta o datos en url y en href de etiqueta <a>

Tags: jsp

soy un poco nueva en jsp y requiero algo que la verdad no se como solucionar.
Estoy enviando datos de jsp a un servlet yo uso method post para enviar datos, pero en algunos casos necesito usar etiquetas  `<a></a>` pero entonces eso si se ve en la url cuando la oprimo y en el inspector como podria hacer para evitar esto ??

Ejemplo:

```
 <a href="controlador?action=Verdoc&iddoc=${doc.getIddocumento()}">
```

Comment: No es problema que se vea el dato, siempre que no sea ningún dato sensible como usuario y  contraseña.

Comment: Es un ID de un documento asi mismo envio id de usuarios o algo y nose si sea malo mostrar a que servlet envio eso

Comment: No hay ningún problema con eso. Solo ten cuidado cuando envíes ids de validar en el servidor que quien envió ese id tenga permiso de consultarlo. Por ejemplo si el usuario actual solo puede consultar el documento 1 y cambia la url y pone documento 2 pues no debe poder verlo.  Y si quieres un poco más de tranquilidad puedes encriptar los valores que envías al cliente y desencriptarlos cuando regresan al servidor, es algo opcional.

Comment: Si eso hago valido primero lo que llega a los servelets para validar si el usuario con una session si deberia tener acceso a eso de lo contrario no lo deja sino que pense que no debia mostrarlos pero las validaciones en el contralados si las tengo para dar permiso si pasa o no pasa

Comment: OK eso seria otra encriptar los ids y al recibir desencriptar y pasarlos a los metodos del modelo